# Initializing a Properties object using Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a class that extends Properties used to store some specialized key names:

```java
public class StorageConfiguration extends Properties {
    private final String PROPERTY_NAME_1 = "property.key";

    public String getProperty1() {
        return this.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_1);
    }

    public void setProperty1(String property1) {
        this.setProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_1, property1);
    }
}
```

And a class that uses these properties:

```java
public class Storage {
    StorageConfiguration storageConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    public void setStorageConfiguration(StorageConfiguration storageConfiguration) {
        this.storageConfiguration = storageConfiguration;
    }

    public void init() {
        // Initialize properties in this class using StorageConfiguration.
    }
}
```

I have my Spring set up to initialize Storage and StorageConfiguration like so:

```xml
<bean id="storage" class="com.k4rthik.labs.Storage" init-method="init">
    <property name="storageConfiguration" ref="storageConfiguration" />
</bean>
<bean id="storageConfiguration"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="storageConfiguration">
        <props>
            <prop key="property.key">property_value</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What I expected would happen was Spring would initialize the StorageConfiguration object by setting the property "property.key" to "property_value".

However I get the following exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'storage' defined in class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'storageConfiguration' while setting bean property
>   'authorizationConfig'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'authorizationConfig' defined in class path
>   resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'storageConfiguration' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean]: Bean
>   property 'storageConfiguration' is not writable or has an invalid
>   setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return
>   type of the getter?

As you can see, I have an autowired setter for storageConfiguration in the Storage class, so I don't really see what's wrong here.

Comment: Your `storageConfiguration` bean is of class `class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"`. Is this correct ?

Comment: Why are you injecting the `storageConfiguration` into `storage` in your XML configuration **and** annotating the setter with `@Autowired`? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: You can't use the final keyword if you want a setter.  Final means that the value won't be modified within the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PropertiesFactoryBean creates a bean of type Properties.

To create a StorageConfiguration, you could create a Copy constructor

```
public class StorageConfiguration
{
    public StorageConfiguration(Properties defaults) {
        super(defaults);
    }
}
```

Then this should work:

```
<bean id="storageConfiguration" class="..StorageConfiguration">
  <constructor-arg>

   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="property.key">property_value</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
  <bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Or even:

```
<bean id="storageConfiguration" class="..StorageConfiguration">
  <constructor-arg>   
        <props>
            <prop key="property.key">property_value</prop>
        </props>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Brilliant. This works. (Tried the smaller solution). Removed the @Autowired tag from storageConfiguration variable first and then this answer works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

it should be

```
<bean id="storage" class="com.k4rthik.labs.Storage" init-method="init">
    <property name="storageConfiguration">
         <props>
            <prop key="property.key">property_value</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

the config

```
<bean id="storageConfiguration"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="storageConfiguration">
        <props>
            <prop key="property.key">property_value</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

means that `StorageConfiguration` of type `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean` has a property called `storageConfiguration`, which doesn't look like as per your code

Comment: That won't work: setStorageConfiguration expects the specific subclass of Properties. <props> always creates the superclass afaik.

Comment: Looks like @greyfairer is right. I'm getting a TypeMismatchException. Let me try his answer next.